# Using sys.stdout.buffer.write as input for subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm currently struggling with communicating to a subprocess.
To explain the situation:
I have a class that endlessly writes to the sys.stdout

```
    def runGenerator(self):
        while self.runEvent.is_set():
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('I', self.next()))
```

(self.next is an unsigned 32 bit integer)
This works fine so far, even though sys.stdout.buffer.write is a bit slow.
But now i create a subprocess in which i call a module named diehader like this:

```
    def runSub(self):
        args = [DIEHARDER, GENERATOR_NUMBER, '-d0']
        dieharderTestProc = subprocess.Popen(
            args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        print(dieharderTestProc.stdout.readlines())
        self.runEvent.clear()
```

And my goal now is to use the sys.stdout (that is generated by the previous function) as the stdin of this subprocess. But i can't seem to find a solution. 
I wan't to keep the input in sys.stdout because my end goal is to have multiple subprocess which can all just use this one sys.stdout, so that i need to generate these numbers only once.
Also these numbers are generated while the subprocess is running as another multiprocess(for time reason). 
That means I can't just give the subprocess a list or some object with my numbers, because they are generated on the spot.
The only way I got the communication to work was like this:

```
        while dieharderTestProc.returncode is None:
            dieharderTestProc.stdin.write(struct.pack('>I', struct.pack('I', self.next())))
            dieharderTestProc.poll()
```

But this way I would have to generate these numbers for every subprocess that i call separately, which just cost to much time.
Thanks for any solution, ideas or tips you can provide me :)

Comment: You're going to have to write to the `stdin` of each subprocess separately - but you could certainly generate the data once, and then call each `.write()` in a loop.  If you were to connect all of the subprocesses to your `stdout`, it would be unpredictable which one actually received any particular item of data - it would NOT be replicated to each subprocess.

Comment: Alright thanks, makes sense. I will try something else then. I'm considering Manager.list() but that seems to be way too slow, because of all the communication. Do you have an idea what would work?